# Selecting based on __key__ (a unique identifier) in google appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Again i have

```
""" A site message """
class Message( db.Model ) :
  # from/to/ a few other fields
  subject = db.StringProperty()
  body = db.Text()

  sent = db.DateTimeProperty( auto_now_add=True )
```

Now I'm trying to pick out a Message by its KEY.  I saved off the key earlier and planted it in an HTML form.  The result is a clickable link that looks something like

```
<a href="/readmessage?key=aght52oobW1hZHIOCxIHTWVzc2FnZRiyAQw">click to open</a>
```

So then I run this GQL query:

```
gql = """select * from Message where __key__='aght52oobW1hZHIOCxIHTWVzc2FnZRiyAQw'"""
```

But its not working because

> BadFilterError: BadFilterError: invalid filter: __key__ filter value must be a Key; received aght52oobW1hZHIOCxIHTWVzc2FnZRiyAQw (a str).

I'm totally missing something here, and that is **how do you put an *object* into a GQL query string.. and not have Gql parser complain of that it is a string?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't bother with GQL for key-based retrieval -- make a key object from the string:

```
k = db.Key('aght52oobW1hZHIOCxIHTWVzc2FnZRiyAQw')
```

and just `db.get(k)`.  If you insist on GQL, btw, that `k` -- a suitably constructed instance of `db.Key`, **NOT** a string object!-) -- is also what you need to substitute into the GQL query (by `:1` or whatrever).

Comment: OH!  And that will always work?  So keys aren't only unique across a table, they're unique across.. my entire webapp?  All webapps for all time?

Comment: @'bo'*4, keys are SERIOUSLY unique -- from a key you can get the entity's `.app()` (so uniqueness across apps is a given), `.kind()` (so uniqueness WITHIN the app's no problem either), etc.

Comment: It's also worth noting that .get takes about a third as long as doing a query.

Comment: @Nick, yep, I should have mentioned this has the advantage of speed as well as simplicity.

Comment: Do you have any idea about how to do the same in the Java version? 
There is no db class :(

Answer (score 1):

You can also construct a query by hand by constructing "[an entity key literal, with...a complete path of kinds and key names/IDs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference.html)".

```
SELECT * FROM Message WHERE __key__ = KEY('Message', 'message_key')
```

This is even more helpful if you are using the Datastore Viewer/Explorer and can't use Python syntax.